# What does "in ten-second chunks" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I came across this sentenece and I am not sure what the exact meaning of it, especially the expression "in ten-second chunks".

> This snapchat story depicts the life of a modern-day Lydia Bennet **in ten-second chunks**.

Would anybody like to interpret for me?

Comment: Are you familiar with how SnapChat works?  Because that's integral to understanding what they mean by "ten-second chunks"

Comment: @Andrew No, I am not. Snapchat is banned in my country. Would you please give me an explanation?

Comment: And what does the word "chunk" mean here? A piece? A period of time?

Comment: Chunk = piece. Piece of what? Time. Piece of time = interval of time. Ten-second chunk = ten second interval of time. ...presto!

Comment: *Cut the tree limb into one-foot chunks for firewood.*  *Cut the meat into one-inch chunks for stew.* *He read the textbook in two-chapter chunks*. The adjective (one-foot, one-inch, two-chapter, ten-second) tells us what kind of chunk (piece) it is (physical object, time, book, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapchat):

> Snapchat is an image messaging and multimedia mobile application created by Evan Spiegel, Bobby Murphy, and Reggie Brown, former students at Stanford University, and developed by Snap Inc., originally Snapchat Inc. **One of the principal concepts of Snapchat is that pictures and messages are only available for a short time before they become inaccessible.**

Content on Snapchat doesn't stay forever -- your friends see the photos and videos (but can't save them) and then the content is automatically deleted.  The service is very popular with younger users, and some adult parents of those younger users.

This is what is meant by "ten-second chunks".  A "chunk" is a block or large, discrete piece of something, in this case of time. Content on Snapchat only exists for this brief period of time, before it is gone.  If you followed this particular fictional user Lydia Bennet, you would get to experience her life -- but only for short periods each time.

Comment: For additional context, note that *stories* are actually a feature of Snapchat, not a general idea. Stories are a bunch of snaps (each of which is no more than 10 seconds long) strung together into a mini movie. I find your phrasing of "short periods each time" slightly confusing for this reason – because we're not talking about a bunch of individual snaps, but rather a bunch of them strung together. We're saying something like "this is a movie of Lydia's life where each scene is only 10 seconds long." Also, you can actually rewatch stories multiple times; they don't delete immediately.